# What does the type mean?

Tags: haskell, newtype

This is the newtype:

```
newtype Combine a b = Combine { unCombine :: (a -> b) }
```

I'm having problems understanding many things about this line, but the first is the braces. What are they and what do they do here - create a function from two input datatypes?

Comment: If newtype confuses you then I suggest you read a tutorial or two and hang out on #haskell at irc.freenode.net to ask questions.  Are the concepts of algebraic data types new to you?  It's ok to say yes!  I've found this concept confuses many people I when I discuss Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The braces allow for record syntax. It can be considered short-hand for the following:

```haskell
newtype Combine a b = Combine (a -> b)

unCombine :: Combine a b -> (a -> b)
unCombine (Combine a) = a
```

Record syntax creates the `unCombine` function for you automatically so you don't have to define it for yourself. It comes in handy when your types have a lot of type parameters.

Comment: Do not understand a lick of what this thing does though. But I guess that is something for another question. Will wait with accepting till tomorrow.

Comment: It doesn't really do anything. It's just a wrapper around a function that takes an argument of type `a` and returns a value of type `b`. After, say `let f = Combine (\x -> x + 3)`, you could run `(unCombine f) 5` and it would return 8.

Comment: Note that record syntax is **not** strictly equivalent to the above code. For example using record syntax you can do `(Combine id){unCombine=const 1}` . That's just part of what they can do.